# When we do a linear fit, what is the correlation coefficient of the estimated parameters?

Tags: mathematics, quantum-advantage, google-sycamore

[image]

In Google's quantum supremacy experiment, supplementary Section VIIIH, they calculate the correlation coefficient of the linear fit coefficients $p_0$,$p_1$. I can't figure out the definition of this quantity. Is this the same as the Pearson correlation coefficient?